# How to install acoustic panels on a door?

Tags: doors, mounting, acoustic

I want to add some foam acoustic panels to a wooden (interior, roughly 30x80 in) door - they are roughly 12x12x2 inch squares, and quite light, to the point where I think double-sided tape would be enough to hold them in place - however, I would like the option of being able to relocate them at some point (door is likely to be replaced at some point in the future) and would like to stay away from glues/sticky stuff because those seem fragile enough to be destroyed if they were to be pulled off from something like that - Any ideas as to how to proceed?

I was thinking perhaps a wooden grid "frame" to hold them, where they would just be "stuffed" into the frame, like this:

[image: http://www.rulonco.com/images/thumbnails/cubes/LAY-IN-cube.png]

and then mounting the frame similarly to how a large mirror would be mounted.

Any issues with doing it like this? any better ways?

Comment: Snip the part after the question mark, make it an answer, and proceed.

Comment: @Ecnerwal was kind of looking for alternatives/potential issues

Answer (score 1):

You could glue/tape the panels to a sheet of tempered hardboard (ie, Masonite®) or thin plywood and mount that to the door. Properly sized, your grid method should also work, and might look nicer.

Comment: Any particular glue/tape that wouldn't destroy the foam panels when removed, or are you suggesting that I remove the entire board with the panels and all for when I want to move it?

Comment: Remove entire board with foam as a unit. Thus you can choose any compatible glue based solely on compatibility, not on removeability. If the foam manufacturer won't suggest a glue (they should be happy to) plain old hot glue often works well.